# candy_check gem ruby 3+ `require': cannot load such file -- google/api_client (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using `Ruby 3.0.1`. I am trying to verify Google play store subscription.
I am facing the below error:

> **`require': cannot load such file -- google/api_client (LoadError)**

I tried many solutions but did not get good luck solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same issue I faced while Play store receipt verification earlier.
Here is a solution:

- Uninstall all previous versions of `gem 'candy_check'` from your system.
- Uninstall `gem 'google-api-client'` installed versions
- Add gem in your **Gemfile** like below

  `gem 'candy_check', git: 'https://github.com/Badiapp/candy_check', branch: 'upgrade/google-api-client'`
- Remove Gemfile.lock and install bundle: `bundle install`.

The same issue is mentioned in gem's raised issues [here](https://github.com/jnbt/candy_check/pull/65#issuecomment-867887771)